# Favorite Activities

Tags: activities

I was building a search with search kit and saw there's an option to pull activities that have been starred but I don't see where I can star activities and Google is giving me nothing. Does anyone know anything about that feature?

Answer (score 1):

It's in the two civicase-related extensions (either https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.civicase or https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicase)

[image]

Comment: aha! Thank you so much!